# Identifying relevant distances from a second table using data.table

Tags: r, data.table

I have four taxa from a phylogeny. I have cut the phylogeny into "generations" to identify groups of related taxa at particular cut points (clades). An example of this can be seen in the data.table below:

```
library(data.table)
clades = data.table(generation = rep(c("g0", "g4"), each = 4),
                    taxa = rep(c(LETTERS[1:4]), times = 2),
                    clade = c(1:4, 1, 1, 2, 2)
                    )
```

At time zero, everyone is unrelated to each other, and at time 4, A and B are in a clade together, and C and D are in a clade together.

I also know the geographic distance between each taxa, stored in a long format here:

```
distance = data.table(
    row = c("A", "A", "B", "A", "B", "C"),
    col = c("B", "C", "C", "D", "D", "D"), 
    value = c(1.41, 5.65, 5.83, 5.83, 5.65, 1.41)
  )
```

I want to efficiently calculate, within each generation, and within each clade, the number of taxa that are within a certain distance, say 2 in this example, and how many comparisons there are total - to give the probability that two taxa are within a certain distance of each other.

```
distance$cut = distance$value < 2
```

In this example, in generation 0, there should be four clades, each of which have no pairs within the cut off, and no pairs (because all clades contain a single taxa). At time point four we should have two clades and within each clade should be one pair within the distance, and one pair compared. Like the below table:

```
result = data.table(generation = c("g0", "g0", "g0", "g0", "g4", "g4"),
                    clade = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2),
                    numerator = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1),
                    denominator = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1))
```

I have managed to do this using *apply functions, but it is quite slow and I need to do this at scale. If anyone can suggest a fast approach I would appreciate it.

```
generations = unique(clades$generation)
output = lapply(generations, function(g) {
  generation_df = clades[clades$generation == g]
  clade_sets <- unique(generation_df$clade)
  
  clade_result <- sapply(clade_sets, function(cs) {
    clade_taxa = generation_df$taxa[generation_df$clade == cs]
    trait = distance$trait[distance$row %in% clade_taxa & distance$col %in% clade_taxa]
    
    if (length(trait) >= 1) {
      numerator = sum(trait)
      denominator = length(trait)
    } else {
      numerator = 0
      denominator = 0
    }
    list(numerator = numerator, denominator = denominator)
  })
  
  # Combine clade result with generation and clade information
  data.frame(
    generation = g,
    clade = clade_sets,
    numerator = unlist(clade_result[1, ]),
    denominator = unlist(clade_result[2, ]),
    stringsAsFactors = FALSE
  )
})
dplyr::bind_rows(output)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this benefits from having `distance` as a matrix for quick lookup:

```r
distance_m <- dcast(row ~ col, value.var = "value", data = distance)
distance_m <- as.matrix(distance_m[,-1]) |>
  `dimnames<-`(list(distance_m[[1]], colnames(distance_m)[-1])) 
distance_m[lower.tri(distance_m)] <- distance_m[upper.tri(distance_m)]
distance_m
#      B    C    D
# A 1.41 5.65 5.83
# B 5.65 5.83 5.65
# C 5.83 5.65 1.41
```

From here,

```r
out <- clades[, if (.N == 1L) list(num=0, den=0L) else {
  m <- combn(taxa, 2)
  list(num=apply(m, 2, function(z) distance_m[z[1], z[2]]), den=ncol(m))
}, by = .(generation, clade)]
out
#    generation clade   num   den
#        <char> <num> <num> <int>
# 1:         g0     1  0.00     0
# 2:         g0     2  0.00     0
# 3:         g0     3  0.00     0
# 4:         g0     4  0.00     0
# 5:         g4     1  1.41     1
# 6:         g4     2  1.41     1
```

and from here one can easily reduce `num` to be a "count below 2":

```r
out[den > 0, num := +(num < 2)]
#    generation clade   num   den
#        <char> <num> <num> <int>
# 1:         g0     1     0     0
# 2:         g0     2     0     0
# 3:         g0     3     0     0
# 4:         g0     4     0     0
# 5:         g4     1     1     1
# 6:         g4     2     1     1
```

Comment: I can't make the assumption that there will only ever be two taxa within a clade, sorry.

Comment: That intro paragraph was from a first iteration of code, I should have deleted it earlier. This should work with more.